# Store userlvl in mysql DB correctly in `$_SESSION` to recall it

Tags: php

I am checking a user level in my mysql data base to let a link appear, if it matches.

This is my current code:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'name', 'psw', 'db');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE user_level = 1 ")) {

    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);
    }
    /* until here everything works fine - the code below seems to be not working */

if ($result == $_SESSION['userlevel']) {

    $link = 'AdminLayout.php';
    printf ('<a href="' .$link. '">Adminpanel </a>');
    /* close result set */
    $result->close();


}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

The `printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);` is only to check whether the connection is working and that it detects the user_level = 1.

I store the `$_SESSION['userlevel']` in my login form with :

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{ 
session_start();

$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'name', 'psw', 'db');


 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
 else ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE user_level = 1 ")) {
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result == 1) {
$ulevel = $mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $ulevel = $_SESSION['userlevel'];
  }
}
}
?>
```

Unfortunately my login form doesn't work anymore with these lines added.

Can anybody help me making it work? How do I store the userlevel of the logged in account correctly, to recall it on another site?

Long story short: I want to check the userlevel in my MySQL DB and let the link appear, if the logged in user matches it.

Comment: If you have a specific problem with mysqli, please narrow your question down to this very problem. The same goes with mysql. Please be specific. Questions like "here is my code it doesn't work" are of topic

Comment: The problem is, that I don't know how to specify it correctly, because I don't really know where the mistakes is. I simply want to store the userlevel in my Session to check it on another site, to "activate" a link. But anyhow, as I tried to store it in  `$ulevel = $_SESSION['userlevel'];`, my loginform doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: NEITHER anyone else knows. At the same time, you have the ability to *run* your code and see where the problem is. Moreover, you are the only one who have the access to your code and environment. So start running it and check the state on every step.

Comment: How do I get any Information, where the problem is? The only result I get is, that my loginform doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: output your variables. use echo, var_dump. check the every function's result and see if it's right or wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Please correct your code as follow.
Login Page:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{ 
session_start();

$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'name', 'psw', 'db');


 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
 elseif ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE user_level = 1 ")) {
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
$_SESSION['userlevel'] = $mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  }
}
}
?>
```

and the other code:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'name', 'psw', 'db');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE user_level = 1 ")) {

    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);
    }
    /* until here everything works fine - the code below seems to be not working */

if ($result == $_SESSION['userlevel']) {

    $link = 'AdminLayout.php';
    printf ('<a href="' .$link. '">Adminpanel </a>');
    /* close result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: My Loginform works again, thank you! But the link ist still not displayed.